# String literal binds to a non-const char pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

void myprint(const char* fmt, ...)
{
  std::cout << "1 ";
}

void myprint(const char* fmt, char *x)
{
  std::cout << "2 ";
}

int main()
{
  const char* s = "c";
  myprint("a", s);
  myprint("a", "b");
}
```

It produces different output:

- [GCC](http://rextester.com/FRX58318) and [MSVC](http://rextester.com/RAGTP26923): `1 2`
- [clang](http://rextester.com/IUS58046): `1 1`

My question is two-fold:

1. Why does a string literal bind to a non-const `char*` even in the presence of `-std=c++14`? Isn't a string literal `const` since C++11?
2. The ellipsis-overload is always ranked lowest. Why does clang select it? (one would think it doesn't allow binding to `char*` but if I remove the ellipsis overload, it still does - [demo](http://rextester.com/LALIF98887))

What's going on and who is right?

Comment: Well you see, one major problem is that your parameters fit in both signatures

Comment: Modern GCC says: "warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]". Looks like GCC is just lenient, but knows that it's being naughty. (That is, GCC gives string literals the wrong type, presumably for reasons of "compatibility" with C.)

Comment: It is a bug in GCC and MSVC. Since C++11 the compiler is required to quietly select the first overload for `myprint("a", "b");`. GCC selects the second with a warning (or with an error in `-pedantic-errors` mode). Warning/error does not make its behavior correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does a string literal bind to a non-const `char*` even in the presence of `-std=c++14`?

It's a deprecated conversion, which has been officially removed from the standard starting with C++11.

> Isn't a string literal `const` since C++11?

No, a string literals is and has always been `const`.

> The ellipsis-overload is always ranked lowest. Why does clang select it?

Because the other one is not valid. There is no conversion from `const char*` to `char*`, for the same reason that there is no way to convert a `const std::string&` to a `std::string&`.

So overload resolution skips that one and chooses the only remaining overload (which also happens to be valid), and prints `1`.

> one would think it doesn't allow binding to char* but if I remove the ellipsis overload, it still does

Yes, that is a non-standard extension, just like the gcc one. You should try to compile with `-pedantic`.

> What's going on and who is right?

clang is definitely right. An extension is not allowed to modify the behavior of a well-formed C++ program ([[intro.compliance]p8](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#8)), so gcc and MSVC are wrong to use the second overload, as the standard doesn't support implicit conversions from `const char*` to `char*`, and should thus fall back on the first one.

To reiterate, your demo is in compliance with the standard because that program is ill-formed according to the standard (the string conversion) and they issue a diagnostic, and so it doesn't run afoul of the paragraph linked above.