# Can pointers be used for accessing any arbitrary area in memory?

Tags: c++

I am extremely new to C++ and pointers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* c = "my name jeff";
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        cout << *(c + i++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "my name jeff" followed by a lot of random characters, occasionally making sense. Am I actually accessing memory in my computer ? Why can initialize a pointer from a string ?

Comment: The behaviour is undefined, so you can epect [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) if you do that.

Comment: If you run a program inside an OS, you cannot access memory which wasn't assigned by your kernel to your program. If you write a kernel module, you should be able to access anywhere in memory, from that kernel module. Etc... It only depends where you program is supposed to be running.

Comment: `char* c = "my name jeff";` is invalid, it should be `const char* c = "my name jeff";`.

Comment: The C++ standard imagines an abstract machine, to which the rules of C++ apply.  Compiler makers convert the C++ source to an executable format suitable for your platform.  The parts of the C++ language that explicitly or implicitly declare as undefined behavior means the compiler makers are at liberty to assume those things don't happen (usually for optimization purposes).  So if your code doesn't follow the rules, ANYTHING could happen.  Including destroying the planet.  Which is bad.

Comment: Code like this is a big reason why protected-mode operating systems work they way they do.  Preventing you from accessing "all memory".  You tend to get bored looking at the wildly scrolling output before the OS decides to terminate the program because it is trying to read from a non-mapped address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note about this line right here:

```
char* c = "my name jeff";
```

In modern C++, [this should be a `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46919323/10957435) instead:

```
const char* c = "my name jeff";
```

---

With that out of the way, the answer to your question is yes and no.

Yes in the sense that if you have some sort of pointer, C++ doesn't care what you put in it.

```
char * pointer = nullptr;
char a, b, c;

pointer = &a;
pointer = &b;
pointer = &c;
```

The pointer doesn't care what address is stored in it. It is arbitrary in that sense. As long as it is the same type, you're fine.

You can even do pointer arithmetic like this:

```
*(pointer + 1) = 1;
*(pointer + 2) = 2;
*(pointer + i) = i;
```

In most cases, this will usually at least compile and probably run. In **theory**, you could use this type of arithmetic to access any given address and see what data is stored there.

**However**, in practice, the answer is a big no. That is because [accessing unallocated memory is undefined behavior in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881098/10957435). If you're unaware, [undefined behavior allows anything to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32132574/10957435), including crashing or printing weird characters.

So, if you have some array like this:

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int * pointer = arr;

std::cout << *(pointer + 7);
```

This is undefined behavior because only `pointer + 3` is guaranteed to have allocated memory in it.

So, in short: Yes, you can theoretically reach any address you want with pointer arithmetic, but you can only access memory that has been allocated safely. So in practice, not really.

Comment: Oh I just realised that const char* is basically a string. Thanks

Comment: Sort of. There is such a thing as an [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which is what C++ usually thinks of as a string. But a `const char *` is close. You can read about it more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1287306/10957435).

Answer (score 2):

From https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#add-4

> When an expression J that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression P of pointer type, the result has the type of P.
>
> (4.1) If P evaluates to a null pointer value and J evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.
>
> (4.2)
>   Otherwise, if P points to an array element i of an array object x with n elements ([dcl.array]),77 the expressions P + J and J + P (where J has the value j) point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element 
>   i
>   +
>   j
>    of x if 
>   0
>   ≤
>   i
>   +
>   j
>   ≤
>   n
>    and the expression P - J points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element 
>   i
>   −
>   j
>    of x if 
>   0
>   ≤
>   i
>   −
>   j
>   ≤
>   n
>   .
>
> (4.3)
>   Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So, with `"my name jeff"` (which is of type `const char[13]` (with the extra `'\0'`)), once you do `c[14]` you have UB.

Comment: Even though it should be noted, with the fact that C/C++ are system programming languages, that it is totally not undefined behavior if you set a pointer to an arbitrary address, for example if you want to access registers located there in an embedded system. So, the compiler makers are not really at liberty to prevent such things as it would defeat the purpose.